# In what cases do isotopes cause non-negligible effects in chemicals

Tags: quantum-chemistry, isotopes

For example, CO2 (carbon dioxide), there could be Carbon8-Carbon22 isotopes, and I'm not sure for oxygen. Wondering at what point there is some sort of non-negligible effect, and what the effect(s) typically look like.

This question isn't about CO2, it's about any chemical which is composed out of several atoms, anything you would find on pubmed. I would like to know from a physics perspective, or quantum-chemistry perhaps, if there are any examples of non-negligible effects of isotopes on the overall chemical structure. And even if it is negligible, wondering what happens when there is a different isotope. It must do *something*.

Comment: Do you only care about structure or also about reaction rates?

Comment: It was suggested that you ask this further question on Chemistry... See xhttps://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484180/207455

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I would like to know everything on the topic.

Comment: It seems like a reasonable physics question to me.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/116372/why-there-is-a-difference-between-atoms-and-chemicals

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope_effect

Comment: @G.Smith based on the comment to your own answer by John Rennie ...

Comment: John Rennie suggested that the OP *consider* posting to Chemistry, which indicates he probably thinks it doesn’t belong in Physics. I respect his opinion but have my own opinion. If enough people, or a moderator, agree with John, the question will get closed or moved.